# Surjective, but not Injective Linear map between C[0,1]

Tags: analysis, banach-spaces, differential-operators

Given the Banach space $C[0,1]$={$f$:$[0,1]$$\longrightarrow$$\mathbb{C}$, continuous} equipped with sup norm,

I would like to find a bounded linear operator $T$ : $C[0,1]$$\longrightarrow$$C[0,1]$ that is surjective but not injective.

And all I can think of is a differential operator, but not all continuous functions are differentiable.

So a differential operator wouldn't work unless the domain is restricted.

I have come up with $T(f(x))=f(\frac{x}{2})-f(1-\frac{x}{2})$

T is not injective, but I am not convinced if T is even surjective.

So any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not surjective, in fact for all $f$ we have $Tf(1)=f(1/2)-f(1/2)=0$. So the image is contained in the set of continuous functions that vanish in $1$.

Comment: What about $Tf(x) = f(x/2)$ ?

Comment: Isn't $Tf(x)=f(x/2)$ injective?

Comment: @A.Colin: No, because only the values of $f$ on $[0,1/2]$ are used to compute $Tf$.

Comment: It's discourteous to delete your question (which was not a bad question) after receiving an answer...

Answer (score 4):

$T: C[0, 1] \to  C[0, 1]$ defined by $Tf(x) = f(x/2)$ is an example.

For any $g \in C[0, 1]$, $T^{-1}(g)$ is the set of all
$f \in  C[0, 1]$ satisfying
$$
 f(x) = g(2x) \text{ for } 0 \le x \le \frac 12
$$
and that are infinitely many.

More generally, as demonstrated in [functions between function spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381336/functions-between-function-spaces/381352#381352), for any continuous  $\varphi: [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$
the mapping $T$  defined by $Tf(x) = f(\varphi(x))$ 
is surjective but not injective exactly if $\varphi$ is injective but not surjective.

Comment: Thanks. Great help!